# Is it possible to emulate or run android on a TI-NSPIRE

Tags: android, internet-connection, ti-nspire

My friend showed me a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skbuc_pQj9g) of someone emulating android on a TI-NSPIRE CX CAS with an internet browser. I researched it, but I cannot tell if what I am hearing is fake or not. I did find out however that TI-Nspire's have the capability to access the internet but only with a yellow attach-on to the top of the calculator called 'Navigator Wireless Network Adapters' (which is very expensive). So, i was wondering how was someone able to access the internet/run android (without the attach-on) or was the video a fake. Either way, is it possible to run android on a calculator. I've heard of crazy things being done with Nspire's like switching OS, playing GBA games, and more, but this is a step further (if it's real). I have a TI-Nspire CX CAS so if it's possible can someone start me off on how to do this (if possible). I appreciate any effort, so thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this link: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/port-android-ti-nspire-cx-t3143757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this, and I don't recommend anyone else to, but this how you would:

As @fragg stated, it's not emulating - you can run android natively on a CPU.

Step 1: "Jailbreak" your calculator

Step 2: Format the USB drive correctly
(You only **need** 2 partitions as ext4)

Step 3: Download android files at: https://github.com/nDroidProject

Step 4: Install TiLP and create directories (should've been instaled at sometime during step 1)

Step 5: Extract system to USB drive `sudo tar -xpf System.tar.gz
sudo rm System.tar.gz`

Step 6: Starting it up: unpulg usb drive and start startndroid.ll2.tns (from your computer)

Step 7: Boot up and finish (may take a while)

Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/port-android-ti-nspire-cx-t3143757